# Script/Batch to Ping Server at Regular Intervals & Log Slow Response Times

Tags: networking, batch-file, ping

I'm having issues with my network connection and would like to be able to ping a remote server at regular intervals (say 1-5s) and log those request which take longer than a defined period of time (say 500ms) to a log file, timestamped.  Is there a way to do this via a script or batch file or something that can run continuously on my client machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the `ping` command you get the time to answer:

```
C:\Users\Private\TEST>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [173.194.70.138] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.194.70.138: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=50
Reply from 173.194.70.138: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=50
Reply from 173.194.70.138: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=50
Reply from 173.194.70.138: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=50

Ping statistics for 173.194.70.138:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 24ms, Maximum = 25ms, Average = 24ms
```

Just grab the time with a  `for /f` loop, compare it with 500 ( `if %PingTime% gtr 500`) and write the grabbed time with a time stamp (eg. `%date%-%time%`) to your logfile. Set the commands in a `goto` loop to repeat it.

Comment: It would need to parse time outs as well as reply lines, and ping might switch to reporting seconds instead of milliseconds if the delay is large enough - I'm not sure - that would complicate the code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Full solution is posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final batch I was able to create to solve the problem.  This batch does not account for the case where there is a 'request timed out' response to a ping.  Since the slow response times always happen in large chunks of time, simply capturing slow ping response times was sufficient.

You can simple modify the "serverName" and "maxPingTime" varables as your case dictates.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set serverName=myServerName
set maxPingTime=120

:loop 


REM // execute a ping command, iterate over each line returned, & note the 5th string (space-delimited)
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('ping -n 1 %myServerName%') do  (

  REM // store the 5th string in a variable
  set pingToken=%%a

  REM // we only want the line for which the first 4 characters of the 5th string equals "time" (i.e. "time=120ms")
  if "!pingToken:~0,4!" equ "time" (

    REM // strip off the last 2 letters of the string (i.e. "ms")
    set tokenWithoutUnits=!pingToken:~0,-2!

    REM // strip off the first 5 letters of the string (i.e. "time=")
    set pingTime=!tokenWithoutUnits:~5,3!

    REM // Compare the ping time to some maximum value of millisseconds
    if !pingTime! gtr !maxPingTime!  (

      REM // Write the date, time, and ping time (in ms) to a text file
      echo %DATE%-%TIME% !pingTime! >> slowpings.txt

    )   

    REM // Wait for 4 seconds before issuing another ping
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 5 > nul
  )


)

REM // jump back to the beginning of the loop
GOTO :loop
```